# send and receive sms of specific number --android

Tags: android, sqlite, sms, smsmanager

I am work on a messaging system which is send and receive sms but the requirement is the application send sms to specific number which is store in its database and it also receive sms from specific number which is store in its database . actually the client is manufacturer of GPS system with GPRS in this system a sim card is stored which is reply when the sms is send it like current location and many function .when sms will receive which number is store in database of application the sms is not show in android phone default program which is already installed in device. tell me how can i start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SmsManager to send sms.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

You can use BroadcastReceiver to receive sms.
Several tutorials are available online to understand BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: thanks its work but msg show in device default program
can you please give me some reputation to up vote you